# Does swapping a pair of edges of a graph reduce its chromatic number?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Let $G$ be a graph with chromatic number $n$ with no proper subgraph of $G$ having chromatic number $n$. Let $u, v, w\in V(G)$ be such that $uv\in E(G)$ and $uw\not\in E(G)$. The graph $G'$ is obtained by removing the $uv$ edge from and adding the $uw$ edge to $G$. Is it true that the chromatic number of $G'$ must be $n-1$?

I know that the statement is true iff there is a coloring of $G$ without the $uv$ edge (that has chromatic number $n-1$) in which the vertices $u$ and $w$ have different colors, but I was not able to make progress from that point.

Comment: You have edited out "minimum number of edges" – that's good – and edited in "minimal graph", which is still unclear. Is my 5-cycle a counterexample?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes, it is. "Minimal graph with chromatic number $n$" means a graph which don't contain a proper subgraph with chromatic number $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A counterexample is given by the five-cycle $a-b-c-d-e-a$. Its chromatic number is three. It is minimal in that if you remove any edge the chromatic number goes down to two. But if you remove $a-b$ and put in $a-d$ then the chromatic number remains three.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: With the clarified definition in your question I debated deleting my answer, but decided that I could change it to offer a smaller counter-example than suggested in other answers *provided non-connected graphs are permitted*. If they are not, I think this should be added to the problem statement.

Let $V(G) = \{u,v,w\}$ and $E(G) = \{uv\}$. $G$ has only one proper subgraph which preserves $V(G)$, having chromatic number $1$.

$\chi(G) = 2$. The only possilbe applications of the rule to $G$ produce $E(G') = \{uw\}$ or $E(G') = \{vw\}$. In either case $\chi(G')$ is still $2$.

Comment: Sorry, eyes glossed over. Didn't realise you weren't the OP. I see. The example you gave involving a $5$-cycle has the same problem though, no? Removing any edge decreases the chromatic number? I only ask to make sure I haven't missed your point.

Comment: Reducing the chromatic number is a requirement, not a problem. In your example, the chromatic number is two, and it's still two after you remove an edge – that's a problem, if my guess as to what OP means by "minimum number of edges" is correct. (In my example, the chromatic number is three, and removing any edge reduces the chromatic number to two, thus meeting the requirement)